# Отправка base64 строки с сервера на клиент

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, base64

Есть задача. На странице есть `input type file`. В него пользователь добовляет картинку. С помощью `FileReader` она конвертируется в base64 и вставляется в `img src`. На странице отобразилась картинка. В итоге я буду передавать её на сервер и сохранять в бд. А в дальнейшем когда буду редактировать запись, эта base64 строка будет передаваться на клиент и должна будет вставляется опять же в `img src` что бы пользователь увидел какая картинка у редактируемой записи. Для быстроты тестирования у меня пока что 1 контроллер в который передаётся base64 строка и сразу же выкидывается назад. Есть 2 тестируемые картинки, побольше и поменьше. Обе прилитают на клиент в access ajax запроса, но та которая побольше при попытки вставки в `src` вылетает с ошибкой, а та которая поменьше вставляется но почти вся кортинка размывается.

JS:

```
//Добавление нового автомобиля
    $('#modalWindow').on('click', '#btnConfirm', function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/_AddNewCar",
            data: $('form').serialize() + "&base64img=" + $('#autoPicture').attr('src'),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#autoPicture').attr('src', data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    //Изменение содержимого загружаемого файла
    $('#modalWindow').on('change', '#fileLoader', function () {
        ReadImageUrl(this);
    });

    function ReadImageUrl(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#autoPicture').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#autoPicture').attr('src', '');
        }
    }
```

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
        public String _AddNewCar(Car car, string base64img)
        {
            return base64img;
        }
```

Изначальные изображения:

1) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот по первому которое побольше при попытке вставить в src вылетает вот такая вот ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А по второй картинке ошибки нет но после вставки base64 в src вот что в результате выходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело? Я ведь даже со строкой нечего не делаю, отправляю её назад сразу.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что раз вы сами добавляете параметр в виде `&x=`, то не помешает делать encodeURIcomponent от значения. в bse64 ведь знаки + и = есть, первое когда придет на сервер будет расценено как пробел, а второе вообще может сломать разбор параметров

Comment: @Mike это же я просто передаю параметр, вы бы не могли привести пример как нужно использовать `encodeURIcomponent`?

Comment: @Mike потому что я сверял длинну строки перед отправкой на сервер и после возвращения с сервера, всё одно и то же. Но всё же попробовать можно, только приведите пожалуйста пример как это нужно селать.

Comment: `$('form').serialize() + "&base64img=" + encodeURIcomponent($('#autoPicture').attr('src'))`

Comment: @Mike огромное спасибо, вчера целый день потратил лазия везде где можно и на стеке тоже. Помогло. Оформите как ответ, я поставлю галочку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При прямой передаче данных на сервер необходимо что бы в строке оказывались только допустимые в url символы. Функция `serialize()` для формы делает это автоматически. Но в строках base64 могут встречаться не допустимые символы которые должны быть соответствующим образом закодированы при передаче. Это делается с помощью JS функции `encodeURIcomponent` :

```
....
data: $('form').serialize() 
    + "&base64img=" 
    + encodeURIcomponent($('#autoPicture').attr('src')),
....
```

Comment: Mike огромное спасибо.